# What rockets use a methalox propellant?

Tags: engines, fuel, methalox

I’ve found that the SpaceX Raptor rocket engine and the BE-4 rocket engine use methalox (Liquid Methane and Liquid Oxygen), is there any other rocket engines that use a methalox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No orbital class rocket so far has used [methalox](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant#Methane). But there are multiple orbital class methalox engines / rockets in development right now, in what has (tongue-in-cheek) been called [the methalox race](https://nasaspaceflight.com/2022/03/methalox-race-to-orbit/):

- [LandSpace (蓝箭航天)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/LandSpace)'s [Zhuque-2 (朱雀二号)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/LandSpace#Zhuque-2) (using its own [TQ-12 (天鹊-12)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/TQ-12) engines),
- [United Launch Alliance](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Launch_Alliance)'s [Vulcan Centaur](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_Centaur) (using Blue Origin's BE-4 engines),
- [Relativity Space](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_Space)'s [Terran 1](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Terran_1) (using its own [Aeon 1](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeon_1) engines),
- [SpaceX](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX)'s [Starship](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) and [Super Heavy](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship#Super_Heavy_booster) (using its own [Raptor 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor#Raptor_2) engines),
- [Blue Origin](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Origin)'s [New Glenn](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Glenn) (using its own [BE-4](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/BE-4) engines),
- [Rocket Lab](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab)'s [Neutron](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab_Neutron) (using its own [Archimedes](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_(rocket_engine)) engines), and
- Relativity Space's [Terran R](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Terran_R) (using its own Aeon R engines).

The predecessor of [Firefly Aerospace](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_Aerospace), [Firefly Space Systems](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_Aerospace#Firefly_Space_Systems) planned to power the original 1.0 version of its [Alpha (α)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_Alpha) rocket's first stage with its own [FRE-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_engine#Firefly_Aerospace) engine, an [aerospike](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_engine) engine burning methalox. The second stage engine, FRE-1, was planned to be a methalox engine as well, with a conventional bell nozzle.

However, the current 2.0 iteration of Alpha uses Firefly's Reaver engine, burning [keralox](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_rocket_propellant#Kerosene), i.e. [RP-1](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/RP-1) and liquid oxygen.

If you want to know why methalox has not been used much until now, this question on this site may be of interest to you: [When was liquid methane used for the first time in rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45860/6156)

It is likely that at least one of these will at least attempt an orbital launch in 2022. It is also highly likely (in my opinion) that Vulcan Centaur's first orbital launch attempt will result in a successful orbital insertion. Hence, I would expect at least one attempt in 2022 and at least one success at the latest in 2023.

Comment: Zhuque-2 reached orbit in July 2023.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LandSpace#Zhuque-2