Is methalox actually any better than hydrolox?
I have been reading a lot about the fact that many SpaceX systems are using (or plan to use) methalox-burning engines, running on the reaction $\text{CH}_4+2\text{O}_2\to 2\text{H}_2\text{O}+\text{CO}_2$, instead of hydrolox, which is the simpler $2\text{H}_2+\text{O}_2\to 2\text{H}_2\text{O}$, theoretically because it’s cheaper and more dense (smaller fuel tanks!).
Methalox burns hot enough that engines can get specific impulses in the high 300s, versus around 450 for hydrolox. That seems like a big difference to me; even if hydrolox is substantially less dense the engines are much more efficient, wouldn’t that make hydrolox still more valuable as fuel?
Having estimated the delta-v of the Starship rocket using methalox vs. hydrogen engines, methalox is better for going faster just because it’s denser and more can be carried, but it seems to me like for the purposes of getting out of Earth’s atmosphere it would be better to carry less, more efficient fuel, thrust being equal (see the RS-25s that can produce plenty of thrust running on hydrogen).
What purpose does choosing methalox serve here?

What rockets use a methalox propellant? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/60181/what-rockets-use-a-methalox-propellant?rq=1

For SpaceX, the main point of using methane is that it can be synthesised on Mars. So when they finally reach Mars, the idea is to produce fuel there to be able to get back.

"methalox is better for going faster"..."for purposes of getting out of Earth's atmosphere" - what's the difference?

@DarkDust the ISRU aspect is primary? I had always read that as more a secondary benefit than a primary concern. Thank you for the clarification.

Interestingly, your intuition in the last paragraph is actually backwards - you want a less efficient, higher-thrust fuel to get out of Earth's atmosphere, and a more efficient, lower-thrust engine while in space.

just fyi, if you like to include a lot of chemical equations, we also have access to MathJax Chemistry notation

Intuition is a poor substitute for calculation and calculation is the only way that you will be able to arrive at a definitive answer. But it really does depend on what you mean by better. If better is just better exhaust velocity then yes, but so what? What really counts is $/tonne to orbit and on that measure hydrogen is a bad choice as it is  too low density and it requires too much tankage. It is expensive to produce, it enbrittles many metals on prolonged contact making it harder to reuse components and It requires a lot more energy to liquify and keep liquid as it is a super cryogen

@controlgroup: I don't know if it's the primary aspect, but a very important one. And when you consider this, it makes sense to go methalox now: by the time you reach Mars you want a methalox spacecraft that is absolutely reliable and well-known.
